# Google map pinch gesture zoom/heading not working

Tags: java, android

What may be the reason why pinch zoom and heading/bearing (pitch) in google maps stops working in split screen mode. when the application is on the left side it is OK, when it is on the right side pinch zoom does not work, where to look for the reason?

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        this.googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false); 
}
```

I create a completely new project, I choose from templates in android studio: "Google Maps Activity" and it's the same. The problem does not apply to all devices, the problems are mainly with Samsung.

Comment: I'd specify the problematic device model so those who have it can provide some insights or test the code. Providing a link to a source code may also be helpful for those who have time to try reproducing the issue.

Comment: The problem occurs, for example, on the Galaxy Tab A8 / S8.